# SQL select where records match in two fields

Tags: sql, db2

TABLE:A

acctno, ratcod, ssno

select only records where ssno is the same and ratcod contains any of 6,7,8 and the same ssno is found elsewhere to contain ratcod value <> 6,7,8

DATA TABLE A

```
acctno ratcod ssno
123456 6      123-44-5566
23456  4      123-44-5566
12345  1      123-44-5566
654321 6      333-44-5566
664433 6      222-44-5566
222336 2      123-44-5566
554646 4      444-98-9876
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
acctno ratcod ssno
123456 6      123-44-5566
23456  4      123-44-5566
12345  1      123-44-5566
222336 2      123-44-5566
```

Trying the following produces an error
DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0199 - Keyword IN not expected.

```
select tableA.* 
    from (select ssno from refdat1.lnmast lnmast 
    group by lnmast.ssno 
    having sum(case ratcod in (6, 7 ,8) then 1 else 0 end) > 0 
    and sum(case ratcod in (6, 7, 8) then 0 else 1 end) > 0) 
    as ASum 
JOIN tableA 
ON tableA.ssno = ASum.ssno
```

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I first thought that it would be a simple join combination but didn't get that right.  I then thought of the union but did not get the selection I was after.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is: find all ssnos having a ratcod in (6, 7, 8) and having a ratcod not in (6, 7, 8). Once these are found, return all the rows with that ssno.

```
select tableA.*
from (select ssno
      from tableA
      group by ssno
      having sum(case ratcod in (6, 7, 8) then 1 else 0 end) > 0
      and sum(case ratcod in (6, 7, 8) then 0 else 1 end) > 0) 
      as ASum
JOIN TableA 
ON TableA.ssno = ASum.ssno
```